# WYSIWYG - jQuery plugin - insertHTML not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

I'm using Jquery WYSIWYG plugin and have problems with 'insertHTML' and IE

in code I have

```
$('#editor').wysiwyg('insertHtml', '<h1>I'm title</h1>');
```

In Firefox html code is added on cursor position, but in IE at the beginning of whole text.
I's Googling for solution, but nothing found :(

Thank you for any advice to solving that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#editor').wysiwyg('insertHtml', '<h1>I\'m title</h1>');
```

Comment: And maybe `$("#editor").wysiwyg("insertHtml", "<h1>I'm title</h1>");`

Comment: Of course '<h1>I'm title</h1>' won't work. It's not the point of escaping but that, that that in IE8 text is put at the beggining, not at the cursor position.